# Embedded Files in Excel

Tags: excel, embedding

I need some help with embedded excel files within my excel spreadsheet. I have one worksheet within my (master) workbook in which there are multiple (upto 20 Max, min 3) embedded excel files. What I want to do is open each embedded file from that sheet and copy the sheets from the embedded file where cell A1 = Yes into my master workbook.

I.e. Master workbook contains sheets:
Instructions,
SheetWithEmbeddedFiles - Which contains the embedded xlsm files

Each embedded xlsm file is of the same format, just the contents will vary. If A1 = yes, then copy that sheet into my master so the master now contains:

Instructions,
SheetWithEmbeddedFiles - Which contains the embedded xlsm files,
SheetFromEmbedded1,
SheetFromEmbedded2 etc etc

I was able to open one of the workbooks through this
Code:

```
Worksheets("SheetWithEmbeddedFiles").Shapes(1).OLEFormat.Activate
```

but then I'm at a loss on how to copy the sheets from it and move on to the next embedded file.

Can someone please help? This is the last thing I need to do for my program and it seems to be the biggest hurdle

All help would be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Once you have the embedded file open, you could use `Windows(Windows.Count).SheetViews(1).Sheet` to access the worksheet of the embedded file. Once finished, you should close the Window again. The `Windows(...)` part makes use of the fact that the newly opened window will always be the last in the collection. **As a side note**: try the macro recorder which somehow generates code even for embedded Excel sheets.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time out to reply. I was able to build on what you replied to get where I wanted. Thanks! :)

Comment: If you want, you can also answer your own question and post a solution so that others can find it later.